# Nginx behaves differently with the same site configuration in different docker images

Tags: nginx

```
nginx site config
    server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;
    server_tokens off;
    gzip_static on;

    location ~* \.(html)$ {
        add_header 'X-XSS-Protection' '1';
    }

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

it works perfect with docker image `node:14.19.3` (`nginx/1.14.2`), but with `node:14-alpine` (`nginx/1.22.1`) it behaves differently:

- trying accessing `index.html` (or `/`) redirects to default `/var/lib/nginx/index.html` (renders "Welcome to Nginx!"), though `/usr/share/nginx/html/index.html` exists and with permissions everything is OK
- if copy `/usr/share/nginx/html/index.html` to `/usr/share/nginx/html/index.txt`  - it is opened (`http://<<mydomain>/index.txt`)
- if copy `/usr/share/nginx/html/index.html` to `/usr/share/nginx/html/i.html`  - 404 - not found (`http://<<mydomain>/i.html`, well, it just can't find it in `/var/lib/nginx/i.html`)
- if remove the upper `location` block from the site config everything works perfect (there is just no that extra response header)

Comment: You will have to compare the entire nginx config files (not a single one) from machine to machine to learn what are the differences.

Comment: Run `nginx -T` on both setups and compare the differences.